# Android Pie keep reinstalling Google Chrome even disabled

Tags: google-play-store, chrome-for-android, 9.0-pie

I've got [Brave](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brave.browser&hl=en) as my primary browser for my LG V30 (H93230d) running on Android Pie several months ago with Chrome disabled in my settings.

However recently I started to see Chrome appearing in my app drawer with latest version installed even it was previously disabled with **Don't auto-update apps** preference in Play Store.

I tried to disable it and force stop but the issue returns after several days. Any idea how to prevent Chrome to update/install automatically?

Comment: On a lot of devices Google Chrome provides the WebView implementation, which means that every app that displays HTML pages using the Android WebView system uses Chrome. Nowadays Google again prefers the  
[Android System WebView](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview) app to provide the WebView implementation but that is device specific and can be changed in the Developer settings.