# Google Chrome and picture reenabling and reinstalling without authorization or interaction?

Tags: chrome-for-android, 9.0-pie, disable-app

As somebody really wary of Google in general, the first thing I did on my phone was to disable Chrome and Google Pictures, and replaced them by apps from F-Droid

For a few days now, I've seen them reappear in my app drawer, and with careful observation, the play store seems to be re-enabling and reinstalling them by itself when checking if updates are available.

Uninstalling and disabling them again just kick the can down to the next repository upgrade.

[This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219507/android-pie-keep-reinstalling-google-chrome-even-disabled) talk about google chrome, but do not give an explanation for google pictures.

Auto updates are disabled, android 9.

Comment: [Known bug](https://support.google.com/photos/thread/11145626?hl=en) and the link in the answer makes it even more scary

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem I noticed after updating my OnePlus 6 to Android 10. I didn't get the time to investigate the logs when my Play Store, YouTube, Photos, Play Services and GSF kept re-enabling themselves. One thing I realized was that  if I used a third-party app to disable them they got re-enabled after a while. But if I disabled them using Settings app, they never got re-enabled. This is what I suggest for you.

Also, I keep them blacklisted in my firewall, just to ensure they don't connect to internet even if they manage to re-enable themselves.

Comment: I actually disabled them with Settings on the first time, lets hope /e/ comes to my device soon so I can can it alltogether...